# paste code to Jupyter notebook without symbols

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, copy-paste

I tried to paste few lines code from online sources with the symbol like ">>>". My question is how to paste without these symbols?

(Line by line works but it will be very annoying if pasting a big project.)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit > Find and Replace, in which find for `>>>` and replace with empty. Enjoy :)